# Create a new object every time or keep a single one

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns, coding-style, temporary

We use primitive types without considering constructors and destructors. It may be because of that, most of them are stored in the stack. We also use `struct` like `float3` for primitive types. We may also make the same for classes. At the beginning of a function, create a new instance, use it and release the memory at the end of the function.

Instead of using a local variable, if we declared an instance variable at the class level, the variable will exist until the class that holds it is released. This increases the steady memory usage. Further, there should be some update methods that are forwarded to this instance. For example, changing container size may affect the content, so a new size should be forwarded to them.

How should a class keep a reference to a variable to avoid creating the variable numerous times?

I know it is related to the number of times its constructor (or destructor) is called, but I am looking for a general solution. Such as, if the class contains only primitives like x, y, z and they are immutable you should construct them always etc.

A way of deciding which way to choose, making `float3` immutable or making its x, y, and z modifiable.

Comment: I gather you used a machine to translate your question (from Turkish to English). Please show some Java or C++ source code that describes your problem and give more details on what you are trying to accomplish. Otherwise, it is very difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: Your question is tagged [c++] and [java].  Which language are you using?  The answer may well be different, depending on the language in use.

Comment: @  phoad - Pre-mature optimisation is evil.  Analyse performance bottle neck, then try to optimize object creation if needed. There are specific patterns to help specific need. For example,   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern, will help to reduce memory by sharing data as much as possible.

Comment: Flyweight pattern seems well suiting my problem, thank you Jayan. I am trying to write an example to make the statement clearer, thanks Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use primitive types, there is likely no difference.

If you use objects of some more "complicated" types, you will probably have to reset it to a known state before reusing it. This might take at least as much code as creating a new object. It also complicates your code, which is never an advantage.

Unless you notice a particular bottleneck in your code, you should try to keep it simple and easy to read. Don't complicate things until you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 1):

typically you'll want to minimize the scope of a variable to improve performance. also, in Java, always prefer primitives to their wrapper class equivalents.